# Pulling information from array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am using array_count_values and I want to pull any key that has a value greater than > 4 and put in a new array.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: post your code. How is `array_count_values` connected to rest of your task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(array_count_values($the_array) as $key=>$value){
    if ($value > 4){
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect I forgot about being able to do $key=>$value.

Answer (score 1):

using the [array_filter()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function might be a good place to start.